# Python how to loop through an array in numpy at C speed and store some positions

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I am new to python, numpy and opencv. I am playing with the first example of harris corner detector from [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html). My objective is to get an ordered list of all the corners. With this simple code I am able to get the X and Y coordinates of the corners and their value:

```
height, width, depth = img.shape
print height, width
for i in range(0, height): #looping at python speed
  for j in range(0, (width)): 
    if dst[i,j] > 0.9*dst.max():
      print i, j, dst[i,j]
```

However, it is dead slow. I don't know how this is called but apparently with numpy one can loop through arrays at C speed and even assign values, example:

```
img[0:height, 0:width, 0:depth] = 0
```

Can I loop through an array and assign the position of interesting values in another variable? I.e. can I use this on my code to make it faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a mask of elements that would pass the IF conditional statement. Next up, if you need the indices that would pass the *condition*, use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`np.argwhere`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) on the mask. For the valid `dst` elements, index `dst` with the same mask, thus using [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays). The implementation would look something like this -

```
mask = dst > 0.9*dst.max()
out = np.column_stack((np.argwhere(mask),dst[mask]))
```

If you would like to get those three printed outputs separately, you could do -

```
I,J = np.where(mask)
valid_dst = dst[mask]
```

---

Finally, if you would like to edit the 3D array `img` based on the `2D` `mask`, you could do -

```
img[mask] = 0
```

This way, you would change the corresponding elements in `img` across all channels in one go.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using Python 2.X you should use `xrange` instead of `range`, this speeds things up. `range` in Python 3.X has the same implementation as `xrange` in Python 2.X.

If you want to iterate over numpy arrays why not use the numpy enumerator for iteration?

```
# creating a sample img array with size 2x2 and RGB values
# so the shape is (2, 2, 3)
> img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (2,2,3))

> img
> array([[[228,  61, 154],
          [108,  25,  52]],

          [[237, 207, 127],
           [246, 223, 101]]])

# iterate over the values, getting key and value at the same time
# additionally, no nasty nested for loops
> for key, val in np.ndenumerate(img):
>     print key, val

# this prints the following
> (0, 0, 0) 228
> (0, 0, 1) 61
> (0, 0, 2) 154
> (0, 1, 0) 108
> (0, 1, 1) 25
> (0, 1, 2) 52
> (1, 0, 0) 237
> (1, 0, 1) 207
> (1, 0, 2) 127
> (1, 1, 0) 246
> (1, 1, 1) 223
> (1, 1, 2) 101
```